# Ionic 2 - How do I make sense of app.bundle.js errors?

Tags: cordova, typescript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have recently upgraded an app from one of the earlier Ionic 2 Alpha versions to the latest Ionic 2 Beta 10. It has cause some of my code to break, and I'm having a terrible time making sense of the errors I'm getting from the JavaScript console. All of the TypeScript is bundled into this one app.bundle.js file, which is causing the console to point to the wrong area of the code when identifying the error. Ideally, I would see the actual file that is causing the error in the console output.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

```
browser_adapter.js:77EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for ConfigService! (ESOService -> ConfigService)
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:2805:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:27996:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:28033:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:29021:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:29049:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:29012:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByReflectiveDependency (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:29002:21)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:28899:36)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:28871:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._new (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:28860:21)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Comment: The message `No provider for ConfigService! (ESOService -> ConfigService)` is pretty straightforward: you're using the `ConfigService` without adding it in the providers array of any component. Take a look where are you using it and add it in the `providers` array from the top-most component where it must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Many braking change were introduced in different versions like .beta8
look at this github page to change you code according to recent changelog

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Update Ionic and start a new project and reimplement the code according to the changlog, this will hopefully emove all errors